# Can't remove a subview from its superview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I add a `subview` when I touch the `searchBar` to "mask" the rest of the app. Then, I want to remove this view when I touch in it. But nothing happens. Can someone explain this to me ?

Here my code:

```
@property (nonatomic) UIView *blackView;

- (BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar*)searchBar {
    NSLog(@"Touched in searchbar");
    UIView* blackView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    blackView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.3];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleFingerTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(removeKeyboard:)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:singleFingerTap];

    [self.view addSubview:blackView];

    return YES;
}

-(void)removeKeyboard:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    [self.searchBar resignFirstResponder];
    [self.blackView removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad. I created a new variable instead of using the one in the interface. Here the clean code.

```
@property (nonatomic) UIView *blackView;

- (BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar*)searchBar {
    NSLog(@"Touched in searchbar");
    self.blackView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.blackView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.3];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleFingerTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(removeKeyboard:)];
    [self.blackview addGestureRecognizer:singleFingerTap];

    [self.view addSubview:self.blackView];

    return YES;
}

-(void)removeKeyboard:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    [self.searchBar resignFirstResponder];
    [self.blackView removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing

```
[self.blackView removeFromSuperview];
```

Which is fine. But I don't see you set it anywhere. Do this after you create your black view.

```
[self setBlackView:blackView]
```

Comment: That's not enough. That property points to nil object. You need to set it.

Answer (score 0):

in function searchBarShouldBeginEditin you create new variable backView:

```
UIView* blackView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
```

in this case self.blackView isnt this UIView

Define UIView *blackView in interface like this

```
@iterface Controller {
     UIView *blackView;
}
```

then create black view:

```
- (BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar*)searchBar {
    blackView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    blackView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.3];

    ....
    return YES;
}
```

and now remove it:

```
-(void)removeKeyboard:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    ...

    [blackView removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have locally created 'blackView' variable in **searchBarShouldBeginEditing** function, which is not accessible inside **removeKeyboard** function.
Try using property variable which you have declared above.